# What does this Wordpress error mean? Warning: Cannot modify header information

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-login.php on line 362

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-login.php on line 374

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 697

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 698

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 699

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 700

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 701

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/ubermenu.php:1) in /home/quickcli/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 702

I've tried everything I can think of and it just doesn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Ben

Answer (score 2):

It's a common php issue (that impacts anything running php, including WordPress) having to do with whitespace and invisible junk characters at the top of a php file before the opening `<?php` declaration.

Go to the ubermenu.php file and backspace all whitespace before the opening declaration. If that doesn't work, delete the whole plugin via FTP and try uploading it again. If that still doesn't work, reupload a fresh copy of the wp-includes folder.

And see [FAQ Troubleshooting >> Headers_already_sent_warning « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Troubleshooting#How_do_I_solve_the_Headers_already_sent_warning_problem.3F)

Comment: I managed to fix it by contacting the person who built the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

It is a plugin issue, as reported by pluggable.php. Try disabling ubermenu. Make sure that you have the compatible version of Wordpress and the plugin.